# Confusion regarding terms related to API, Web-Services and few more. Any official spec by any org?

Tags: api, rest, web-services, soap, webapi

API

Web-Service

Web-API

Types of API

Difference between an API and a Web-Service

Difference between an Web-API and a Web-Service

REST (Representational State Transfer)

SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol)

RESTful API

RESTful Web-Service

Differences between RESTful API and RESTful Web-Service

SOA (Service-Oriented Architecture)

Monolithic Architecture

Micro-Services

Micro-Services vs Web-Services

Micro-Services vs Web-Services vs Web API

Web Application vs Website vs Web Service

**Few Statements that create confusions more**

Web service is used to communicate between two machines on a network.

Web API is used as an interface between two different applications for communicating with each other.

all web services are APIs but all APIs are not web services

Where can we find the official documentations to all these terms ?

**Questions that can give better picture**

Difference showing the examples (when api call and when web-service call)

subset diagram (API(Preferably Web-API), Web Services, Micro-Services)

key differences (e.g. APIs has endpoints e.g. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE however Web-Services does not have)

Access to the API(Free and Paid) and Web-Services

Comment: Another confusion that REST constraints are optional and things like RESTful have any meaning. By definition all REST services are RESTful and if a service does not meet all mandatory REST constraints, then it is not a REST service no matter what the developer's opinion is or how influential the developer is. Even Facebook and Google don't have REST services as far as I understand their projects.